# Union of bounded and unbounded streams in flink

Tags: flink-streaming

Can we use union to combine a bounded stream from api with unbounded stream from kafka in flink? Would it cause any issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general I would expect this to work. Note that when the unbounded stream terminates, the source will generate a final watermark with the value `MAX_WATERMARK`. This prevents bounded source data from being buffered in state indefinitely, since there won't be any subsequent watermarks.

Also if the streaming & bounded sources have differing parallelisms, there will be a rebalance as a result of the union. If you're expecting data to not get shuffled (from either source), this can mess up that expectation.